# How do I re-use sub-dependencies with NPM correctly?

Tags: javascript, npm, react-admin, peer-dependencies

This question is mostly based on `react-admin`, hence the tags, but it's probably also useful in other situations.

So we have `react-admin` which depends on `@material-ui/core`. This allows me to use Material UI in my own code while implementing the UI without depending on `@material-ui/core` myself. However, what I can't do is use any kind of help from an IDE (VSCode / Emacs + LSP), e.g. I can't auto-import anything from `@material-ui/core`.

I consider this behaviour correct and expected, since `@material-ui/core` is not a dependency of my project. However, I still can *use* that depedency, so I would like my tools to know that. Adding it as my own dependency is rather ugly, since I'd have to keep versions synchronized to `react-admin`'s, which can be a hassle and kind of defeats the whole point of dependency management. I tried adding `@material-ui/core` to *my* `peerDependencies`, which seems to be quite a bit backwards, but surprisingly works for both VSCode and LSP.

So the question is: which is the correct way to re-use sub-dependencies without adding a bunch of unneeded dependencies to my project?

Comment: Having surprise dependencies (not declared) is unexpected and is therefore MUCH MORE UGLIER than adding the dependency directly. On the contrary, adding `@material-ui/core` as a dependency to your code is **beautiful** (which is the opposite of ugly) since it allows maintainers to know what is being used as well as what version is being used by just looking at package.json

Answer (score 1):

At the app's point of view, generally, if you want to use `@material-ui/core` then you should put it in to your dependencies. no idea why you think it is 'ugly'

App shouldn't have peerDeps. peerDeps is designed to be used by plugin/library.